# Make a string safe for CSV writing?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I need to write out to a CSV file using print statements, so I cannot use the CSV writer library. However, as expected, commas break the string into different columns. How can I escape the commas by transforming the string before writing?

For example:

```
my_str = 'I have apples, pears, and bannanas'
with open('test.csv','w', newline='') as out:
    print(my_str, file = out)
```

I need a function like this:

```
def csv_formatter(string):
    # transform string here 
    return csv_safe_string
```

I tried enclosing the string in quote as other posts have suggested, to no success.

Comment: so you want to create a 1 column csv-like output?

Comment: Yes, correct! I want to print the string to one cell.

Comment: you need a csv-file-reader that accepts your "safe" string. Quoting the whole as `'"I have apples, pears and bannanas" , 22, 44'` should do it to get 3 colums

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to emulate `csv` module, just use it, combined with `io.StringIO` to mimic a file output:

```
import csv,io

def csv_formatter(string):
    outstream = io.StringIO()   # "fake" output file

    cw = csv.writer(outstream)  # pass the fake file to csv module
    cw.writerow([string])       # write a row
    return outstream.getvalue() # get the contents of the fake file

print(csv_formatter("I have apples, pears, and bananas"))
```

result:

```
"I have apples, pears, and bananas"
```

Also, a nice side effect is that quotes are taken into account: change to:

```
print(csv_formatter('I have apples, "pears", and bananas'))
```

you'll get (notice the doubled quotes within the quotes):

```
"I have apples, ""pears"", and bananas"
```

Note that this is writing a file with one column. But the same recipy applies with more than 1 column. For instance, replace the write line by:

```
cw.writerow([string,string,12])
```

you'll get:

```
"I have apples, pears, and bananas","I have apples, pears, and bananas",12
```

And now I'm wondering why you cannot mix `print` with `csv` output, just share the file handle:

```
with open('test.csv','w', newline='') as out:
    print("Raw Hello", file = out)
    csv.writer(out).writerow('I have apples, pears, and bananas')
    print("Raw Goodbye", file = out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your string in such way:

```
my_str = '"I have apples, pears, and bannanas"'
```